# Elasticsearch spring data support for user without access to root

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to use spring data to access elasticsearch (reactive client) but my user only have access to my index not to the "/".  When it performs `clusterInfo`, it fails.  Any suggestion on how to bypass the clusterInfo?

Answer (score 0):

This currently is not possible. I'd suggest you open a [ticket in Jira](https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAES/issues) that we implement the possibility to ignore the cluster status checks.

Edit 06.08.2022: The reactive client in the upcoming version of Spring Data Elasticsearch (5.0) does not have this behaviour anymore.